# Store Float from Android into MySql

Tags: android, mysql

I want to store Altitude from barometric pressure into MySql but the result is `null`.

***This is my code :***

```
public SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            float pressure_value = 0.0f;
            float height = 0.0f;
            if (Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE == event.sensor.getType())
            {
                pressure_value = event.values[0];
                height = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,pressure_value);
            }
            value = String.valueOf(height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };
```

In my MySql, the value format is double. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Store Double.parseDouble(value);